# "Isotopes" in a molecule?

Tags: atoms, molecules

I just learned that atoms of the same element can have different mass because of they are isotopes. If there are two isotopes in which each reacts to form the same thing. Would the mass differ in each of the two reactions? Is there a term for compounds just like the term isotope is for the atoms?

Comment: see:[kinetic isotope effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_isotope_effect)

Comment: The "quick questions" without explicitly expressed solving effort are not very welcome. That may lead to hesitation to answer or even to closing a question.  If a question is asked on Chemistry SE site, the site policy expects authors to elaborate the question, e.g. by searching in textbook+online resources, writing what has been found, understood or tried and what is the stumble stone for the answer to be found. SE network aims for a  collection of  high quality answers AND questions.

Comment: It means that "I have just learnt that..." is wrong approach, implying you have not even thought about it much yet nor spent time to search for answers.

Comment: There is no term for that; we just say _"molecules with such-and-such isotopic composition"_.

Comment: @Poutnik Sorry to say, but I actually did some google searches before. I did searched: "isotopes of molecule",
"can the same molecule differs in mass", and many others. Please stop making assumptions.

Comment: These molecule are called isotopologues.

Comment: @HilbertDJ Show then assumptions were wrong by what you have found. It is a basic topic in textbooks and there is plenty of available articles across Internet. Search rather by keyword set than by expressions that may not be used. For scientific topic, add "Wikipedia" keyword while searching, as it may bring you faster to  the topic. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org) is full of articles, like [Isotope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope) or [Isotopic labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopic_labeling).  [Isotopologues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopologue) were  mentioned.

Comment: OK, I stand corrected, there is a term, after all. Now, I vaguely recall having heard that those little plastic or metal pieces wrapped around the ends of shoelaces also have a name, but I don't remember that either.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I have never heard about isotopologues until today either. :-)

Comment: It's kinda sad to see that a legitimate question is being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

If 2 molecules have different isotopes of some element their masses will differ. In this respect there are 2 different terms:

- [Molecular mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_(mass_spectrometry)#Molecular_mass) a.k.a. molecular weight (MW) - is an average mass of a molecule. If we take many molecules (a mole of molecules) of the same substance: some of them will have isotope A, others - isotope B. Their average is going to be MW*. It's used in calculations e.g. when we want to know the mass (in grams) of N moles of some substances. Or vice versa - given the mass (in grams) we'd like to calculate how many moles of there are.
- [Exact molecular weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_(mass_spectrometry)#Exact_mass) - the mass of the molecule with isotope A or isotope B. These are the masses that will differ.

*Note that in atmosphere the isotopes may come in different ratios. E.g. $Cl$ comes as 2 isotopes ($^{35}Cl$ and $^{37}Cl$) - their ratio is 3:1. So MW is not the average of $35$ and $37$, it needs to take the abundance into consideration: $\frac{0.75\times35 + 0.25\times37}{2}$